# Algorithm for finding nearest distance from a point to a curved surface in space

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, polar-coordinates

I need to write an algorithm which can find the nearest distance from a point in space to a 3D curved surface which is straight in vertical direction but its projection is an arc of a circle (Similar to a paper folded like a curve in one axis).  Please help with the procedure.

Comment: So your surface is (part of) a cylinder with axis parallel to the $z$-axis? In that case ignore third coordinate and look at distance from your arc of circle to the projection of the point in the $xy$-plane.

Comment: actually the axis of cylinder makes a certain angle with the z-axis! apologies for not mentioning that before.